# Image sent as attachment instead of inline in email sent through apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am used [this code](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/mail-merge) for a rich-text mail merge and it worked great.

I then modified it to add a variable {{imageBlob}} to the template, which I then replace by the image tag and include that as inline image using the option feature of GmailApp.sendEmail

This worked fine the first time I tested it. But all subsequent tests result in the image being sent as an attachment!

```
/*in function to set the template*/
        template = template.replace(templateVars[i], "<img src='cid:imageKey' style='width:24px; height:16px;'/>");

/*in function to send email*/
        var imageUrl  = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.png/320px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.png";
      var imageBlob=UrlFetchApp
                                .fetch(imageUrl)
                                .getBlob()
                                .setName("imageBlob");


         GmailApp.sendEmail(row[RECIPIENT_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text,{
              htmlBody: msgObj.html, cc:row[CC_COL], inlineImages:{imageKey: imageBlob}
            });
```

Comment: In your script, it seems that `template` is not used. How about this? And can I ask you about `msgObj`?

Comment: I have only included excerpts from the full code (https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/mail-merge) which I have modified to add the inline image.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your current situation from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

To implement inserting an image in the draft email, I used a new column in the template sheet named "image" where I put this line:

```
<img src='cid:imageKey' style='width:24px; height:16px;'/>
```

And in the draft email I used `{{image}}` where I want the image to be replaced.

The sendEmails function would stay the same as you have it, only adding/replacing the following lines:

```
/*in function to send email*/
var imageUrl  = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Flag_of_the_Netherlands.png/320px-Flag_of_the_Netherlands.png";
var imageBlob=UrlFetchApp
.fetch(imageUrl)
.getBlob()
.setName("imageBlob");
GmailApp.sendEmail(row[RECIPIENT_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {
  htmlBody: msgObj.html, inlineImages:{imageKey: imageBlob}
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding the column as well. It is still sent as an attachment for me. Is it sending as inline image for you?

Comment: Yes, I put `{{image}}` inside the gmail draft. Try creating a new draft and check it doesn't have "Plain text mode" activated.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "doesn't have plain text mode activated" ? What should be the mode of the draft?

Comment: HTML, which is the one used when plain text mode is not on.